# How to run mongodb via npm script?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

Under the script in my package.json, the code is written as:

```
  "scripts": {
    "db": "mongod",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon app.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run db\" \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "postinstall": "cd client && npm install"
  },
```

I want the mongodb to start running after typing in `npm run dev`. However, it failed and the error messages showing up in my command prompt were as follows:

```
[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[0] npm ERR! errno 100
[0] npm ERR! projectName db: `mongod`
[0] npm ERR! Exit status 100
```

There is no problem running mongodb if I open a separate terminal and type `mongod`. It only arises when I try to run the database, server and client in one line of code via `npm run dev`.

Comment: Why would you run mongodb via npm script? Just enable it as a service on your host, like it should be done. Try to set the `--dbpath` argument

Comment: Do you mean to just add something like `startmongod:"mongod --dbpath ........"` under the script? Is it because everyone might install the db in different path on their local machine so that it's not a good idea to run it via npm script? I just thought it will be more convenient for those testing the project to get everything up and running with just one line of code

Comment: @Marc I think I should rephrase my question and put it as "How to run MongoDB automatically with Node.js project"

Comment: If you Application depends on a Database, then its a requirement. Assume MongoDB is installed and running. What do you do who has mongodb not installed? The script throws a error and the user is even more confused. If you already assume mongo is installed (as you do in your script), you can assume too its up and running. Your thoughts seem like a problem that dosnt really exists.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for clearing things up. The assumption I made when posting this question is the latter( I assume the user has mongodb installed on the local machine) and I want the mongodb to start running automatically when they test the application. Sorry I feel a bit confused about the part you mentioned to assume it's up and running. The user still has to do something for starting the mongodb, right? Why doing this extra step for them via npm script isn't a good idea?

Comment: Because when you decide to install mongodb, you usally install it as a service, so its up and running when you OS boots. Why install mongo and then dont start it? If i dont want to use/start it then in dont need to install it. If you app require its, then i have to install it and (depends on your OS a little bit) its start automatically on every boot.

Comment: @Marc I really appreciate your patience and explanation and it really helps me a lot but I also notice some people might install mongodb as executables rather than a service in development. In this case, manually starting the mongodb server is required. But I start to see why this step might not be necessary because it can vary from computer to computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to simply start mongo before your project then best approach will be just write a shellscript which executes command to perform your operations , and to save and check command output you can write that logs in another file . in your Case below will be the best idea, create file called runLocalSetup.sh and add below code

```html
#!/bin/bash
exec &> logfile.txt

service mongod start
npm run dev
```

above code will start mongo service and then execute the app, and create the log of command output